# R: Isolating Maps for Viewing and Export

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, qgis

I'm attempting to view one map separately from a raster stack of maps each with unique titles. When I run the map function, all 5 maps included in the raster stack are displayed side by side (see below). I am only interested in viewing and exporting the last. How would you go about isolating this map? Below is an image of the outputs and a link to the  plotting function I'm using.

https://github.com/azizka/sampbias/blob/master/R/map_bias.R

[Raster Stack maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKtpG.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

With these data

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
s <- rast(c(f, f, f))
```

You can plot all three layers

```
plot(s)
```

Or a single layer (here the second)

```
plot(s, 2)
```

Or a subset

```
plot(s, 2:3)
```

Alternatively, you can first subset `s` like this to get the second layer

```
r <- s[[2]]
```

And then use

```
plot(r)
```

Or functions from other packages. The above is for `SpatRaster` objects from the `terra` package. But it works the same for the `RasterStack` objects from `raster`.